# What are ways to control the time delay in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timedelay

I've looked around and apparently I've got the choice between these libraries/ solutions:

One:

```
public void Awake() {
    Invoke("InvokeAndPrint", 2);
}

void InvokeAndPrint() {
    print("InvokeAndPrint 2");
}
```

Two:

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(2.0F));
}

IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
}
```

I want to know if there is any other better way?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Can't use `await` with Unity3D due to requirement of .NET 3.5

Comment: @Micky Always feel both written not so good Code looks very messy.

Comment: (Agreed. I've never been a fan of either sadly).  The only other method I can think of is old-school take note of the time at start; then in your `Update()` method check for elapsed time.  You essentially do everything yourself.  Though way more verbose than the above examples, it's type-safe and does not require any extra threads or thread job objects

Comment: yeap, @Micky 's right, that would be your only option

Comment: @Micky Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: @NikaKasradze Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: @Foskill You are most welcome good sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is a summary of my comments above

---

The only other method I can think of is old-school take note of the time at start; then in your `Update()` method check for elapsed time. You essentially do everything yourself. Though way more verbose than the above examples, it's type-safe and does not require any extra threads or thread job objects.

### Simplest

First we need some fields defined:

```
private DateTime _start;
private bool _done;
```

In your start take note of the time:

```
void Start()
{
    _start = DateTime.Now;
}
```

...then in your update check to see how much time has elapsed. If its greater than your timeout of say 2 seconds, fire off what-ever you wish to do - in this case `print()`:

```
void Update()
{
    if (! _done && (DateTime.Now - _start).TotalSeconds >= 2)
    {
        print("hello world");
        _done = true;
    }
}
```

That's it.

### Re-usable Code

You'll probably find that there are many places where there is a need for this so wouldn't it be groovy if there was a way to cut down on repeated code.  Perhaps a class to wrap it up in?

```
class DelayedJob
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _delay;
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly DateTime _start;

    public DelayedJob(TimeSpan delay, Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }
        _delay = delay;
        _action = action;
        _start = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if there is more work to do, false otherwise</returns>
    public bool Update()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now - _start >= _delay)
        {
            _action();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
void Start()
{
    _job = new DelayedJob(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), ()=> print("hello"));
}
```

...after updating your `Update()` accordingly:

```
void Update()
{
    if (_job != null && !_job.Update())
    {
        _job = null;
    }
}
```

### Multiple Jobs

It's just a matter of placing them in a collection and processing it at runtime.

```
private List<DelayedJob> _jobs; 

void Start()
{
    _jobs = new List<DelayedJob>
            {
                new DelayedJob(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () => print("star wars")),
                new DelayedJob(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3f), () => print("is coming!"))
            };
}
```

...a few alterations to `Update()`:

```
void Update()
{    
    bool again;

    do
    {
        again = false;
        // you probably want to optimise this so that we don't check the same items
        // at the start again after removing an item
        foreach (var delayedJob in _jobs)
        {
            if (!delayedJob.Update())
            {
                _jobs.Remove(delayedJob);
                again = true; // start over
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (again);    
}
```

Comment: That's what I want to answer Thank you again!

Comment: @Foskill No worries buddy and thank-you too.  I should have jotted it down in the first place.  Happy Unity'ing :)

Comment: Hah Happy Unity'ing too :)